# Speeding up textbox textchanged event with sql server connection to search for values

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, connection-pooling, textchanged

I have an application with a textbox textchanged event to search values in a database.

Now its realy slow typing characters in the textbox.
I read somonewhere that this is happening becase it needs to make a connection to the database for each character you type in the textbox. But i have also read that all the sql connections stay open in a pool so you can use them again. (so what is true becase if the pool thing is true it should be fast right?)

the solution i trie was implementing a timer so that i know when user stops typing and then search the database so it only has 1 connection. the speed was good when i was typing but because it now came on another thread i needed to implement this rule in page_load

```
System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
```

but now i am getting all kind of errors on the datagridview and some weird behavior i dont understand.

So my question is:  is there another solution to speed this up or is the timer event the only one.

thanks in advance

Comment: Why go for such complex ui? give a button to user to search and on button click look for DB. Or if your database is no huge prepopulate the combo then search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False`! And if you do not want to block your UI-Thread, you have to run the (time)expensive operation in the background.

```
Private Sub ExpensiveFoo(s As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Me.Invoke(Sub() ExpensiveFoo(s))
    Else
        TextBox2.Text = s
    End If


End Sub


Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    Console.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim s As String = TextBox1.Text
    Task.Run(Sub() ExpensiveFoo(s))

End Sub
```

The TextChanged Event now simply starts a `task` which will do some work in the background and when it's done, will update a second textbox - WITHOUT using the dreaded `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False`

Comment: Oke i tryd it and put my database search running query in Sub ExpensiveFoo but than again i will get errors becase of the threading.

Comment: If you use `InvokeRequired` and `Invoke`, you will NOT get an exception. Whatever operation you execute, you always have to make sure, to run it in the correct thread. `Invoke` (on the correct object) just does this.

Comment: Tanx m8 nice solution i never worked with     InvokeRequired before